# Error during model startup root: Could not setup the parameter: because of: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException:

Tags: anylogic

Currently I am running a model that's read values from Excel spread sheet. The delay value in second linked to parameter which obtain the value from excel sheet 1.

The link between the excel and parameters are working. Moreover, running the model without parameter seems to be working. Can anyone point out what is the error and how can I solve it?
thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extra variables was introduced in excel sheet which code trying to assign it to blocks. I have deleted the unwanted variables from Excel sheet and it worked.